# Solve $\sin^2 x − \cos^2 x = \sin x$, when $x\in -\pi ≤ x ≤\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I have to solve for $x$ using the domain of $-\pi ≤ x ≤\pi$

$$\sin^2 x − \cos^2 x = \sin x $$

I tried changing $\cos^2 x$  to $1 - \sin^2 x$, and then getting

$$\sin^2 x - 1 + \sin^2 x = \sin x \to 2\sin^2 x - 1 = \sin x$$

Then I have no clue where to go from there. Please help!

Comment: Hint: trigononemtric identities and double angle formulae.

Comment: Another hint: Write $\sin(2x)-\cos(2x)$ as $\sin(2x-\frac\pi4)$.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you mean $\sin(2x)-\cos(2x) = \sin x$ or $\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x = \sin x$.

Comment: oops sorry guys, I meant sin^2 x - cos^2 x = sinx

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2 x -\cos^2x = 2\sin^2 x-1$; now it's a quadratic in $\sin x$.

Comment: im still confused

Comment: We have $$\sin x=\sin^2x-\cos^2x=-\cos2x=\sin\left(2x-\frac\pi2\right)$$


$$2x-\frac\pi2=n\pi+(-1)^nx$$

Answer (score 2):

From
$\sin^2 x − \cos^2 x = \sin x$,
since
$\cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x$,
$\sin x 
= \sin^2 x - (1-\sin^2 x)
=2\sin^2 x -1
$.

Now we only have $\sin x$,
so let $\sin x = y$.
This becomes
$y = 2y^2-1$.

You can solve this for $y$.
From the possible values of $y$,
you can then get $x$.

I will leave it at that.